# How can I connect to localhost using the Tetherigh Hotspot of a phone?

Tags: android, windows, connection, wamp, hotspot

I can't seem to find a solution for this. Either it hasn't been asked, is impossible, or I used wrong key words, so I'm gonna try and ask here.

My problem is that I have two phones and a laptop.
My Laptop has WAMP 3.0.6 on it and has my database and server.
One phone is connected via tethering USB cable to the Laptop and has its Tethering Hotspot on.
The other phone is connected to the first phone via Wifi to Hotspot connection.
However, when I try to use the method of `http://IP:PORT` on the second phone, it shows a `Not Allowed`or `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` warning instead of my Localhost page.

Can anybody give some help on this?

Comment: `http://IP:PORT`. Please tell exactly which ip you use.

Comment: `One phone is connected via tethering USB cable`. To what?

Comment: `it shows a Not Allowed page `. What is 'it'?

Comment: @greenapps `http://LaptopPreferedIP:PreferedPort` and `every browser i had on my phone`, and also i edited the question, i seem to have accidentally deleted the `to the laptop` bit by accident

Comment: and no i don't use the internet i just want to connect the second phone to the laptop coz i use both phones to connect

Comment: `LaptopPreferedIP`. Please come to the point. I did ask it wasnt it?

Comment: `My problem is that I have two phones and a laptop.`. A problem? Be glad: you are rich! ;-).

Comment: You have a laptop without wifi?

Comment: the laptop and other phone isn't mine. One phone is mine. The laptop is broken so it has no wifi receiver. And the IP is `192.168.***.***` and last time i heard you're not supposed to spread your IP. \:-|

Comment: My god millions of people have ips like 192.168.##.##. We all have the same local ips. What a fuss. What is the ip of the phone that is thethering? And what is the ip of the second phone?