# Can a Phone be used to spread Localhost usage?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-server, connection

Can I use my phone to spread the usage of my WAMP server through Wifi and Tethering Hotspot?

I wanted to know if it could work like what we usually do with an on the site sharing. For example, Minecraft; one can just turn on their Tethering Hotspot and the others connect to it with Wifi so that they could play together.

In this situation however, is that you use your laptop's Wifi to connect to a phone that is hosting a Tethering Hotspot that everyone else (Meaning all laptops and phones that have wifi) is connected to, and share your WAMP server. Eg: your localhost or PhpMyAdmin, and etc.

I wanted to know if it is **Possible** or not, because when I tried to use my friend's wifi, I could't connect because it took too long.

And if it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: you can connect using your laptop's ip by calling it from your phone

Comment: yes but it was only available to the one that it connected to. So the one that hosted the Hotspot was able to do this but the rest of them that connected to it were unable to connect to the server.

Comment: You should give to the point information. Tell the ip of all devices. You are asking the same again as some days ago in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923492 Dont tell that you still use an usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes U can connect your device to access local host.You just need to access your Pc's IP address and port no.

For complete ref. see here:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)